# how to use an if statement to check if something is visible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write an if statement where if an alert appears (`inner_modal_visible`), then click on the continue button (using XPATH for now to test but will change it to class once I know it works on xpath), else continue clicking on `inbound_seat.click()`

If I actually remove the xpath continue button code outside and in the if statement, then it selects all `inbound_seats`, but obviously I cannot continue. If I add the continue button code back in, then I get the error below after I select one inbound_seat.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the if statement to work so that if the alear appears, then click the continue button when it's clickable, else continue selecting the inbound seats?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\mayur\Documents\Selenium\Return Flight - no products.py", line 314, in <module>
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[12]/div[2]/p[2]/button"))).click();
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    TimeoutException: Message:
```

Code:

```
 # choose seats
if inbound_has_infant:
    # select a non-selected infant seat
    inbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".inbound .planebody a.seat.infant:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")
else:
    # select a non-reserved non-selected seat
    inbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".inbound .planebody a.seat:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")

print("Passenger: %s, choosing seat: %s" % (inbound_passenger.text.strip(), inbound_seat.get_attribute("data-seat")))
inbound_seat.click()

modal_inner_visible = driver.find_element_by_id("AllInboundPassengersSeatedOk")

if modal_inner_visible.is_displayed():
    #confirm seats reserved
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[12]/div[2]/p[2]/button"))).click();

else:
    #continue selecting seats
    inbound_seat.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After looping over the passengers*, wait for "clickability" of the appropriate `Continue` button:

```
for inbound_passenger in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ol[data-flightbound='Inbound'] li[data-personid]"):
    inbound_passenger.click()
    inbound_has_infant = inbound_passenger.get_attribute("data-hasinfant")

    # choose seats
    if inbound_has_infant:
        # select a non-selected infant seat
        inbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".inbound .planebody a.seat.infant:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")
    else:
        # select a non-reserved non-selected seat
        inbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".inbound .planebody a.seat:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")

    print("Passenger: %s, choosing seat: %s" % (inbound_passenger.text.strip(), inbound_seat.get_attribute("data-seat")))
    inbound_seat.click()

# proceed to the next page
submit_seat_selection = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#AllInboundPassengersSeatedOk button.submitseatselection")))
submit_seat_selection.click()
```

Comment: Now I understand what ElementNotVisibleException means. Thanks again alecxe.

Comment: Only issue though is that even though all seats are now selected and the message your seats are reserved appears, it doesn't click on the continue button. I tried replacing your CSS selector code with the button which is `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".submitseatselection button"))).click()` but no luck. Tried a few other things but no dice at the mo. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @BruceyBandit the selector you are using would not match the button, it should either be `#AllInboundPassengersSeatedOk button` as I've proposed, or `button.submitseatselection`. Please try.

Comment: I also posted a new question which you may find a challenge. Been trying for last hour but cannot get it. If you're on the meals page and select your meals, the website wants to process the options in the drop down lists you used before continuing. So trying to implement a wait for an option to be processed in a drop down before moving onto the next one but can't seem to get that to work. Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390388/how-to-wait-for-one-drop-down-list-to-be-processed-before-moving-to-the-next-one

Comment: Already tried your version before my version and that didn't click the button. Tried the `button.submitseatselection` as well but still doesn't ciick it. Bizzare. I will try with just By.ID and perform a print to see if it even recognises the pop up appearing

Comment: @BruceyBandit okay, going off, will take a look a bit later. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, FYI, I tried a print after the wait (With your line of code wait but removed the .click() at the end) and it doesn't print anything. So I think it doesn't seem to recognise the continue button in the pop up

Comment: @BruceyBandit updated the answer, you also need to wait for invisibility of the "loading" popup. Check it out.

Comment: @BruceyBandit after looking into your complete code in the other answer, just realized that you can just wait for the Continue button to be clickable after the loop - updated the answer again - works for me.

Comment: Awesome, it was just the button.submitseatselection where I messed up. Classes are awful. Thanks again alecxe