# how to wait for one drop down list to be processed before moving to the next one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Having an issue with drop down menus in my selenium (python). In this page, what happens is that when selecting a drop down option, it will process the selection, making the other options not selectable until that process is finished. I'm trying to say in my script to wait until a drop down list has processed it's option before moving onto the next one, but it's just hanging. How can I get it to wait for the option to be processed in one drop down menu before moving to the next drop down?

Below is what I've attempted:

```
#Meal details
try:
    pax_one_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDown"))
    pax_one_ob_meal.select_by_index(0)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_one_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_one_ib_meal.select_by_index(2)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDown")))
    pax_two_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDown"))
    pax_two_ob_meal.select_by_index(1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_two_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_two_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDown")))
    pax_three_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownt"))
    pax_three_ob_meal.select_by_index(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_three_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_three_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDown")))
    pax_four_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDown"))
    pax_four_ob_meal.select_by_index(0)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_four_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_four_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)
```

You can visit the www.jet2.com page and load up the script below to see what I'm seeing (it's on the meals page as it's the meals drop down options I'm having issues with). After reserving your seats, you will have to manually click on the continue button when 'you have reserved your seats' message comes up as I'm still trying to figure out how to do this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def select_date(calendar, mininum_date=None):
    try:
        # check if "Your Date" is there
        your_date_elm = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("your-date")

        your_date = your_date_elm.get_attribute("data-date")
        print("Found 'Your Date': " + your_date)
        your_date_elm.click()

        # check if your_date against the minimum date if given
        your_date = datetime.strptime(your_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        if mininum_date and your_date < mininum_date:
            raise NoSuchElementException("Minimum date violation")
        return your_date
    except NoSuchElementException:
        flight_date = None
        flight_date_elm = None
        while True:
            print("Processing " + calendar.find_element_by_css_selector("div.subheader > p").text)

            try:
                if mininum_date:
                    flight_date_elms = calendar.find_elements_by_class_name("flights")
                    flight_date_elm = next(flight_date_elm for flight_date_elm in flight_date_elms
                                           if datetime.strptime(flight_date_elm.get_attribute("data-date"), "%Y-%m-%d") >= mininum_date)
                else:
                    flight_date_elm = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("flights")
            except (StopIteration, NoSuchElementException):
                calendar.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Next month").click()

            # if found - print out the date, click and exit the loop
            if flight_date_elm:
                flight_date = flight_date_elm.get_attribute("data-date")
                print("Found 'Flight Date': " + flight_date)
                flight_date_elm.click()
                break

        return datetime.strptime(flight_date, "%Y-%m-%d")


FROM = "Leeds Bradford"
TO = "Antalya"

PAX1_FORENAME = "Dad"
PAX2_FORENAME = "Mum"
PAX3_FORENAME = "Son"
PAX4_FORENAME = "Daughter"
PAX5_FORENAME = "Baby"

PAX_SURNAME = "Test"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.jet2.com")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

# wait for the page to load
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "departure-airport-input")))

# fill out the form
return_flight = driver.find_element_by_id('return-flight-selector').click()

depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input").send_keys(FROM)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ui-id-1 .ui-menu-item"))).click()

go_to = driver.find_element_by_id("destination-airport-input").send_keys(TO)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ui-id-2 .ui-menu-item"))).click()

# select depart date
datepicker = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-date-selector")
actions.move_to_element(datepicker).click().perform()

# find the calendar, month and year picker and the current date
calendar = driver.find_element_by_id("departureDateContainer")
month_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month"))
year_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
current_date = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-current-day")

# printing out current date
month = month_picker.first_selected_option.text
year = year_picker.first_selected_option.text
print("Current departure date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=current_date.text, month=month, year=year))

# see if we have an available date in this month
try:
    next_available_date = current_date.find_element_by_xpath("following::td[@data-handler='selectDay' and ancestor::div/@id='departureDateContainer']")
    print("Found an available departure date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
    next_available_date.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
# looping over until the next available date found
        while True:
# click next, if not found, select the next year
            try:
                calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-next").click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
# select next year
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
                year.select_by_visible_text(str(int(year.first_selected_option.text) + 1))

# reporting current processed month and year
                month = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month")).first_selected_option.text
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year")).first_selected_option.text
                print("Processing {month} {year}".format(month=month, year=year))

            try:
                next_available_date = calendar.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-handler='selectDay']")
                print("Found an available departure date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
                next_available_date.click()
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                continue



# select return date
datepicker = driver.find_element_by_id("return-date-selector")
actions.move_to_element(datepicker).click().perform()

# find the calendar, month and year picker and the current date
calendar = driver.find_element_by_id("returnDateContainer")
month_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month"))
year_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
current_date = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-current-day")

# printing out current date
month = month_picker.first_selected_option.text
year = year_picker.first_selected_option.text
print("Current return date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=current_date.text, month=month, year=year))

# see if we have an available date in this month
try:
    next_available_date = current_date.find_element_by_xpath("following::td[@data-handler='selectDay' and ancestor::div/@id='returnDateContainer']")
    print("Found an available return date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
    next_available_date.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
# looping over until the next available date found
        while True:
# click next, if not found, select the next year
            try:
                calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-next").click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
# select next year
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
                year.select_by_visible_text(str(int(year.first_selected_option.text) + 1))

# reporting current processed month and year
                month = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month")).first_selected_option.text
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year")).first_selected_option.text
                print("Processing {month} {year}".format(month=month, year=year))

            try:
                next_available_date = calendar.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-handler='selectDay']")
                print("Found an available return date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
                next_available_date.click()
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                continue

#select adults
adults = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("adults-number"))
adults.select_by_visible_text("2")

#select children
children = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("children-number"))
children.select_by_visible_text("2")

#children ages
child_one = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("childSelect1"))
child_one.select_by_visible_text("4")

child_two = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("childSelect2"))
child_two.select_by_visible_text("6")

confirm = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Confirm")
confirm.click()

#select infants
infants = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("infants-number"))
infants.select_by_visible_text("1")

#search flights
search_flight = driver.find_element_by_id("search-flights").click()

# get the outbound date
outbound = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "outboundsearchresults")))
outbound_date = select_date(outbound)

# get the inbound date
inbound = driver.find_element_by_id("inboundsearchresults")
inbound_minimum_date = outbound_date + timedelta(days=7)
inbound_date = select_date(inbound, mininum_date=inbound_minimum_date)
print(outbound_date, inbound_date)

# continue after flights selected
proceed_to_pax = driver.find_element_by_id('navigateActionNext').click()
pax_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl08_butAddBagsForAll")))

#select currency
currency = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_dynamicCurrencyDropDown"))
currency.select_by_value("1")

#Passenger details
pax_one_title = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_TitleDropDownList"))
pax_one_title.select_by_visible_text("Mr")
pax_one_forename = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_ForeNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX1_FORENAME)
pax_one_surname = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_SurNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX_SURNAME)

pax_two_title = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl03_TitleDropDownList"))
pax_two_title.select_by_visible_text("Mrs")
pax_two_forename = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl03_ForeNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX2_FORENAME)
pax_two_surname = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl03_SurNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX_SURNAME)

pax_three_title = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl04_TitleDropDownList"))
pax_three_title.select_by_visible_text("Mr")
pax_three_forename = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl04_ForeNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX3_FORENAME)
pax_three_surname = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl04_SurNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX_SURNAME)

pax_four_title = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl05_TitleDropDownList"))
pax_four_title.select_by_visible_text("Ms")
pax_four_forename = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl05_ForeNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX4_FORENAME)
pax_four_surname = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl05_SurNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX_SURNAME)

pax_five_title = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl06_TitleDropDownList"))
pax_five_title.select_by_visible_text("Mstr")
pax_five_forename = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl06_ForeNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX5_FORENAME)
pax_five_surname = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl06_SurNameTextBox").send_keys(PAX_SURNAME)

#pax baggage
pax_one_bags = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_baggageOutDropDown"))
pax_one_bags.select_by_value("0")

pax_two_bags = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl03_baggageOutDropDown"))
pax_two_bags.select_by_value("0")

pax_three_bags = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl04_baggageOutDropDown"))
pax_three_bags.select_by_value("0")

pax_four_bags = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl05_baggageOutDropDown"))
pax_four_bags.select_by_value("0")

#infant carer
infant_one_carer = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl06_InfantCarerDropDown"))
infant_one_carer.select_by_visible_text("Mr Dad Test")

#checkin
#online = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_checkinOnline").click()
airport = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_checkinAirport").click()

#continue to seats
continue_pax = driver.find_element_by_id("pageContinue").click()
modal_outer = wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_PageTransitionDialog_messageWrapper")))
continue_again = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pageContinue"))).click();
seats_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "findyourseat")))

#seats selection - outbound

for outbound_passenger in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ol[data-flightbound='Outbound'] li[data-personid]"):
    outbound_passenger.click()

#driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ol.passengerlist li[data-personid]"):

    outbound_has_infant = outbound_passenger.get_attribute("data-hasinfant")

# choose seats
    if outbound_has_infant:
        # select a non-selected infant seat
        outbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".outbound .planebody a.seat.infant:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")
    else:
        # select a non-reserved non-selected seat
        outbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".outbound .planebody a.seat:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")

    print("Passenger: %s, choosing seat: %s" % (outbound_passenger.text.strip(), outbound_seat.get_attribute("data-seat")))
    outbound_seat.click()

outbound_plan = wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "outbound")))
inbound_plan = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "inbound")))

#seats selection - inbound

for inbound_passenger in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ol[data-flightbound='Inbound'] li[data-personid]"):
    inbound_passenger.click()

#driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ol.passengerlist li[data-personid]"):

    inbound_has_infant = inbound_passenger.get_attribute("data-hasinfant")

    # choose seats
    if inbound_has_infant:
        # select a non-selected infant seat
        inbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".inbound .planebody a.seat.infant:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")
    else:
        # select a non-reserved non-selected seat
        inbound_seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".inbound .planebody a.seat:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")

    print("Passenger: %s, choosing seat: %s" % (inbound_passenger.text.strip(), inbound_seat.get_attribute("data-seat")))
    try:
        inbound_seat.click()
    except ElementNotVisibleException:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#AllInboundPassengersSeatedOk button"))).click()
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".submitseatselection button"))).click()

meals = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_removeMealButton")))

#Meal details
try:
    pax_one_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDown"))
    pax_one_ob_meal.select_by_index(0)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_one_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_one_ib_meal.select_by_index(2)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDown")))
    pax_two_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDown"))
    pax_two_ob_meal.select_by_index(1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_two_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_two_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDown")))
    pax_three_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownt"))
    pax_three_ob_meal.select_by_index(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_three_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_three_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDown")))
    pax_four_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDown"))
    pax_four_ob_meal.select_by_index(0)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDownIn")))
    pax_four_ib_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDownIn"))
    pax_four_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is a bit different - when you select an item from the dropdown, this dropdown becomes disabled until the price is recalculated - see the `disabled` attribute appearing on the `select` element after selecting an option.

So, select an option and wait for the dropdown to be clickable/enabled:

```
pax_one_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDown"))
pax_one_ob_meal.select_by_index(0)

# wait for the dropdown to be clickable/enabled again
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDown")))

# proceed to the next dropdown
```

Comment: @BruceyBandit I hope you'll finally get the tickets for the big "Test" family from Leeds to spend vacation in Antalya :D

Answer (score 0):

Please use the xpath or css locator to locate the element and then use select dropdown using index.Use of  Fluent wait is good to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues :-)

The first issue is:

```
//locator is incorrect it has a t in the end
    pax_three_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownt"))

// it should be
ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDown
```

and the second issue is with the modal dialog box which we are forced to manually click on "continue" button is actually seems to be part of a iframe and you can get around this by switching through the iframes.
This is a very crude way but the below code works though it can be optimized( so add the below code above " meals selection")

```
    framecount = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    for frame in framecount:
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
        try:
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='AllInboundPassengersSeatedOk']/div[2]/p[2]/button"))).click()
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            break
        except TimeoutException:
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            print "Not found in the frame"
    // i could not understand why but until you loop thorugh the iframes the below element is not visiable
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='AllInboundPassengersSeatedOk']/div[2]/p[2]/button"))).click()
//Start of meals section
    meals = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_removeMealButton")))
```

After the above changes the script worked fine for me :-)

Comment: Hi Jyothidhwar, you will have to show me how you implement this in the code as I can't get it to work

Comment: Try this and let me know if you still have issues https://gist.github.com/ishwar6789/ff5e6d95c5c0451d266a